# How is this even showing no such element unable to locate element.My project is to scrap datas from product table from . Help to find the correct xpat

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

[No such element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucR3h.png)

Help me to find the correct Xpath of the website etsy product table https://www.etsy.com/in-en/c/jewelry/earrings/ear-jackets-and-climbers?ref=catnav-10855

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the whole table, then I believe the xpath you are looking for is:

```
//*[@class='wt-bg-white wt-display-block wt-pb-xs-2 wt-mt-xs-0']
```

As far as I can tell the table is the only element with that particular class combination, so I would use that to identify it.
If you use relative xpath it might break due to unforseen chances in DOM structure or css.